# Can anyone tell me what HTML.Action is and in what scenario is it used?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

So far I can understand HTML.ActionLink and URL.RouteURL but still trying to absorb where to use HTML.Action and it's various parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phil Haack wrote a very nice [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) about child actions. `Html.Action` is the same as `Html.Partial` except that a *child controller action* is executed that could return anything and this anything will be inserted at the location you called the helper. It allows you to have a completely separate MVC lifecycle for rendering some *widgets* on your site. It also allows you to cache the partial.

Comment: this is also a superb link for this +1

Answer (score 0):

Excellent explanation [here](https://msmvps.com/blogs/bmains/archive/2010/04/25/rendering-inline-using-html-action-in-mvc-2-0.aspx)